# How to save each figure in a loop using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to save each figure in a for loop in a folder. However for 4-5 runs of the loop only the last figure is saved. Why is it so?
What modifications do I need to make?

```
for t in (0,l[k-1]):
        plt.figure()
        t=resized_right[0:resized_right.shape[0]-1, g+2:g+s+1]
        plt.imshow(resized_right[0:resized_right.shape[0]-1, g+2:g+s+1])
        plt.savefig(dir)
        g+=s-2
        p+=1
        plt.show()
```

where dir is the directory where the image is to be stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `plt.savefig(dir)` with `plt.savefig(dir + str(t))`.
In this way you save `t` different files in the same directory `dir`.

Pay also attention to slashes ´/´ in the directory path. Check it by printing `dir`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the name of file in savefig and in filename you can append t so 1 image can be saved per loop. Otherwise it will be overridden by next one and you will get only last image

Comment: Yeah it was being overridden each time and only the last image was saved. However the issue is now solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your saving a figure named dir and overwrite it evertime.

Try adding a variable in `plt.savefig(dir)`. For Example:

```
 print ("dir" + str(t) + ".png")
```

Comment: Yes I tried and it is solved. Thanks for the help!!